# Two routers, need internet connection, sharing, and wifi on both?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have two routers, one Apple router and a WNDR4500.
The WNDR4500 is the second router and I need to have access to the computers and printers on the first router.

Right now I have a cable from the first router (Apple Router) connected to the WAN port on the second router (WNDR4500).

How do I set up so I can use both routers as wifi access-spots, both have internet and all the printers and computers are available on both?
So I can print and share regardless of which wifi and router I'm connected to.

Comment: I have a small window to do this, so I'm guessing I should disable DHCP on the second router, connect from the first router to the second router via a lan port, and change the SSID so it matches both network, so it's the same.

Comment: Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leave the first router as is.

Configure the second router as follows:

1. disable DHCP
2. give it a static IP address
3. leave the WAN port disconnected
4. connect a cable from the first router to a LAN port on the second router, this will allow DHCP service from the first router which will assign IP addresses to wireless clients
5. rename SSID and change wireless channels to avoid wireless collisions

All your clients on the second router will have access to devices on your first LAN.

Answer (score 1):

You'll most likely need, as you say, to disable DHCP on the secondary router. Have a look at the settings and see if you can get it to run as an access point only - this will disable DHCP itself. The wireless networks will need to have the same SSID and wireless channel however as they are not enterprise wireless network so if you move out of the range of one you may suffer some disconnection when the connection is transferred between the two access points.

I'd connect the cable to a LAN port, not the netgear's WAN port as well.

Comment: Why would prefer to connect the first router to the second router's LAN port instead of WAN? This is because with Netgear WNDR4500 w/ firmware v1.0.1.6_1.0.76, there's an AP Mode (*for access point*) and the [diagram](https://i.postimg.cc/3JGhDHpd/20190212-104543-TUE-netgearapsuperuser.jpg) clearly shows the use of the WAN port. I've noticed that Netgear uses the language of WAN port interchangeably with *Internet Port.*